# Flipping rectangle grid (or flipping tiles) with animation nodes

Tags: animation-nodes

Dear Blender and Animation Nodes Users

I'd like to create a flipping rectangle grid animation with a controller object. I need a tutorial on this, but I am not able to find any, which I deem good or up to date.

A similar effect, and tutorial can be found here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0qYNoXmbHZo

but this one uses python code inside AN, I think Animation Nodes knows the necessary things without writing any code.

Thank you in advance, Michael

Answer (score 2):

You can start by inspecting "Transform Individual Polygons" template. THEN, if you are using AN version 1.6, you have this handy pivot thing:

http://animation-nodes-manual.readthedocs.io/en/latest/release_notes/v1_6.html

There is actually an example over there that allows you to flip polygon face.

A little bit of observation and experimentation and you will have the flip setup.

Comment: Thank you! At the moment I am quite sure I do not have time to try, but thank you anyway.

Michael